# Using Rebus as an ESB

Tags: c#, wcf, rebus

My requirements are to have IIS hosted WCF services communicate via a decoupled mechanism. I'm researching various options for .net. Would Rebus be a good fit and how would I go about satisfying the requirements:

1. WCF services publish messages to Bus Bus takes care of reliable delivery
2. Bus takes care of retrying policies
3. Bus takes care of identity mapping
4. Bus takes care of transformation of messages to WCF requests
5. WCF services receive calls to their WCF endpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use Rebus for that, although some of your requirements need some coding on your part to be fulfilled. Here are my comments:

1) Just `await bus.Publish(yourMessage)` from your WCF service.

2 and 3) That's what Rebus does, moving the message to an error queue if delivery keeps failing.

4) I am not quite sure what you mean by "take care of identity mapping".

5) Rebus does not transform anything for you. It's pretty easy though to create a message handler that makes a WCF request. I guess you can call that process "transform bus message into WCF request".

6) WCF can do what WCF does.

I hope that makes sense - please let me know if there's something you want me to clarify :)

Comment: So for I'll have to create a service (or services) hosting Rebus, which will handle messages. Any generic way of doing this or do I have to create a handler for each message type and route?

Comment: You will have to create a handler for each message type that you intent to handle. You may want to take advantage of "polymorphic dispatch" though, which is the mechanism that makes it possible for you to have `IHandleMessages<ISomeGeneralInterface>` or even `IHandleMessages<object>` if you want to handle everything

Comment: Please note though, that the message still needs to be properly deserialized, so you will probably need to update your generic handler whenever you add new message types.